# Regex to match the string with another string Patten which is /DIG/?

Tags: java, regex, string

like

```
String urlString="http://myApp:8888/new/bin/save/DIG/WebHome"
```

i want to see if this string contains the pattern /DIG/. I think i can use String.matches(String regex) but i am not getting what should be regex for pattern
/DIG/? I am not getting what should be right regex for this? Sorry for asking this as iam very uncomfortable with regex .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about `urlString.contains("/DIG/")` ?

Answer (score 2):

Ademibans answer works perfectly fine.

But to answer your question:

```
.*?\/DIG\/.*?
```

Comment: There's not even need for the `.*?` RegEx will find it if it's there even if you only use `\/DIG\/`. (Since you haven't specified the beginning of ending of the string (`^$`), the search is loose enough, and searches the entire string.